# Let $A$ and $B$ be positive definite matrices and $S_{M}= \{x:x^TM^{-1}x \leq 1\}$ . Show that $S_{A} \subseteq S_{B}$ iff $B \succeq A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

> **Problem**: Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ real symmetric positive definite matrices and $S_{A}= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x^TA^{-1}x \leq 1\}$ and $S_{B}= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x^TB^{-1}x \leq 1\}$. Show that $S_{A} \subseteq S_{B}$ iff $B \succeq A$.

Definition: $B \succeq A \Rightarrow B-A \succeq 0$, in other words $B-A$ is positive semidefinite.

I seem to be getting the opposite result. I do: if $S_{A} \subseteq S_{B}$ then $x^TA^{-1}x \leq x^TB^{-1}x$ and so $0 \leq x^TB^{-1}x-x^TA^{-1}x$ which means that $0 \leq x^T(B^{-1}-A^{-1})x$.

This means that $(B^{-1}-A^{-1})$ is positive semidefinite and thus $B^{-1} \succeq A^{-1}$. But I know that (and previously proved) if $B^{-1} \succeq A^{-1}$ then $B \preceq A$, which is the opposite of what I am trying to prove. Where am I going wrong so far, and how do I proceed?

Comment: If $A \preceq B$ then $B^{-1}  \preceq A^{-1}$, so $x^TB^{-1}x \leq x^TA^{-1}x \leq1$. Hence any $x\in S_{A}$ will also satisfy  $x\in S_{B}$.